# How do you find the mean and variance with new observations?

Tags: statistics

When given a mean and variance of a sample, without knowing the observations, how would you then find the new mean and variance given more observations?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something to consider is whether that mean is a arithmetic mean or a geometric mean as these are quite different to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $\left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right)$ is the sample and let us
call $\mu_n$ the empirical mean of size $n$. Then the updating rule is given
by $\mu_n = \frac{n - 1}{n} \mu_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n} x_n$. This is how to
derive the result
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \mu_n & = & \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i\\
  & = & \frac{n - 1}{n} \times \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} x_i +
  \frac{1}{n} x_n\\
  & = & \frac{n - 1}{n} \mu_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n} x_n
\end{eqnarray*}
The rule for the variance is a bit more complicated but follows from the same
reasoning.